# Compare many char variables in C++

Tags: c++, vector, char

I'm a beginner programmer and i'm confised. How can i compare many char variables?
So, i have in *.in* file smt like that:

> n (an unsigned variable, like 7, how many char are down)
>   A B C C B D B

in *.out* file i must have which characters are repeated and how often repeat:

> B 3
>   C 2

how can i do this? please help me. i think i can use a *for* and vectors... but how?
i tried somthing, but i don't know how to continue :( (*litera* mean *character*)

```
unsigned n,i;
char litera;
f>>n;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    f>>litera;

return 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a counting array:

```
int array[256] = {};
unsigned int n,i;
char tmp;
f>>n;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    f>>tmp;
    array[tmp] ++;
```

after that you can just print into the file all the values in the array that are not zero.

Comment: This is unlikely to work correctly as is, since array is uninitialized.

Comment: ok, this works, thaks a lot :* i combine this version whit @Grzegorz 's version

Answer (score 1):

Simpler way is to use a `std::map< char, int>` that would store the count of each character.

```
unsigned n,i;
f>>n;
char ch;
std::map< char, int > myMap;
for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    f>>ch;
    if ( myMap[ch] )
      myMap[ch]++;
    else 
      myMap[ch] = 1;
}
```

Otherwise Use a vector of char.

```
unsigned n,i;
f>>n;
vector<char> litera( n );
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    f>>litera[i];
```

For counting the number of repititions, there are many ways.

You can first sort the vector and iterate through the elements.

```
std::sort( litera.begin(), litera.end() );

int count = 1;
for ( int i = 0; i < litera.size(); i++ ) {
  if ( litera[i] == litera[i+1] ) 
    count++;
  else if ( count > 1 ) {
    std::cout << litera[i] << count << std:endl;
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As number of possible chars is very limitted (256), you can define an array in size 255 which will represent how many instances of each chars exist.

Start by zeroing such an array. Then iterate your input characters and increment each cell you see. Finally print all non-zero element to output file.

Comment: +1 for the good advice and not writing code. Students really should do their own homework.

Comment: size 255 --> size 256 (indexed from 0 to 255)

Comment: @Notinlist dude, i'm not doing my homework here, i just practice some c++

Comment: @Bogdan Then it is a homework in an other sense. Still, my comment stands :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will not write the whole stuff for I guess you need/want to learn C++ and the best to do it is do stuff on your own. Here is idea, though.

Assuming you are reading ASCII characters only (as you are using char) I would declare a static array:

```
int counts[256] ;
```

and then filled it out initially with zeroes

You can use `memset` or a `for` loop to do that.

Next, when you read characters you increase specific cell of the `counts` array like that:

```
counts[litera]++ ;
```

At the end, when you are done reading, loop through the array and print out letter and corresponding number from the `counts` array:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
    if ( counts[ i ] != 0 )
        std::cout << static_cast< char >( i ) << " " << counts[ i ] << "\n" ;
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: You can't use `reinterpret_cast` to convert an `int` to a `char`, use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: Suggest `int counts[256] = {0};`

Comment: So, i have a warning here: `warning: array subscript has type 'char' [-Wchar-subscripts]`

Comment: @Bogdan: I guess it is at `counts[litera]++ ;` ? If this is the case then you may want to change `litera`'s type from `char` to `unsigned char`. It is because `char` is from -128 to 127, while `unsigned char` is from 0 to 255

Comment: `std::cout` prints on the screen. You need to change my `std::cout` to a line that prints output to your `.out` file.